# Can't connect to localhost database with VSCode Oracle Explorer

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, oracle12c

I have a Visual Studio Code version 1.69.1 project in which I'm trying to connect to my local Oracle 12C database.

I've done it exactly how the documentation says to do it, and I've verified that my local database connection is up and listening; I've verified by connecting through SQL Developer.  Nonetheless I still get the following error:

```
Error opening connection 'USER1.orcl'.Details: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

This is a shot of my Oracle Explorer configuration:

[image: VSCode Oracle Explorer config]

And this is a shot of the exact same connection in SQL Developer - which connects fine:
[image: SQL Developer configuration]

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL developer is connecting using SID while VS code is using service name. Try doing a ````tnsping orcl````

Comment: Please add the output of this command to the question. C:\>lsnrctl status . The issue is clear. Your database does not expose the service "orcl" . Listener status will reveal what services your database exposes.

Comment: You're both awesome.  What I needed to do was use either of those commands to resolve the entire service name - orcl.mycompany.com.  Thanks much!

Comment: If you want you can post as an answer and I'll accept.